# Android ListView - how to execute a code when items are ready?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView which gets items from a db (using SimpleCursorAdapter). After the list is populated I want to scroll it to a given position. I can't find the right place to do this.

Right now I set a "need to scroll" flag before running the query. Then I check this flag in setViewValue() and if it's set I scroll the list and reset the flag. Although this works, I don't think it's the best way to do it.

Any other ideas about how to perform some actions when a ListView is populated?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for a "scroll-to" like method. Here's a quick [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29).

Comment: No, I don't mind how the scrolling is done. setSelection is good enough. The problem is when to call it - the list must be already populated.

Comment: What kind of adapter are you using to populate this list? An ArrayAdapter?

Comment: It's SimpleCursorAdapter (mentioned in the post).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I solved this. Derived my own adapter from SimpleCursorAdapter, overloaded notifyDataSetChanged method so that it scrolls the list when necessary after calling super's method. Looks working.